# Bound a product as seen in a paper

Tags: calculus

How can I prove that there exists positive constants $A$, $B$ such that:

$\dfrac{A}{m^c}<\displaystyle \prod_{v=1}^{c(\log{m})^2}{1-\frac{1}{\log{(m+v)}}}<\frac{B}{m^c}$

with $c$ positive when $m$ tends to infinite.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider the $\exp$ of $\log$ from your expression to transform your product in sum and then make a simple study of the map you obtened

$$m\longmapsto \sum_{v=1}^{c(\log m)^2}\log\left( 1-\dfrac{1}{\log (m+v)}\right) $$

And use that the $\exp$ is an increasing map.